# Is the first (post-tutorial) enemy in Infinity blade 2 supposed to have 4000 hit points?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I'm a level 1... human, I assume?   I have a lovely little sword that does 6 points of damage (1+5), and have 450 hit points.

The first enemy I face is a "Level 1 Shade".  He has a dark, ominous-looking sword that does 20 points of damage.  (Ok, that's cool, I have free will and a lot of patience.)  **But he has 4000 hit points.**

Let me once again point out that my sword does 6 points damage.  While it's possibly a nod to a shade's demonic nature that I must stike him **666** times to kill him, I can't help but wonder if something is amiss.

To put it in perspective, if you assume you get about 4 strikes in each time you have a "break", *you need to break 166 rounds of attacks to beat him*.    (Yeah, yeah, less scratches and stabs, but C'MON.)

Did I somehow inadvertantly activate the "Wish you'd never bought an ipad" difficulty setting?

**UPDATE**:  It was basically a glitch.  Perhaps I quit the app at a bad time, but what happened was that I'd been converted to the weak, post-tutorial character with 400 HP and no infinity blade, but I was still facing the tutorial characters who have 4000 HP like you do in the intro.

**SOLUTION**:  You have to create an all new character in the options menu under "character slots".  Resetting thy our existing character won't fix it.

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to lose to him?  It's almost impossible to beat the God King in your first playthrough of Infinity Blade.

Comment: @Jason, that occurred to me based on the phoenix-y theme in the original.  Tried it and cycled back - still impossibly powerful.

Comment: This happened to me too on my phone. Fix worked as described. I think it's a bug. I first played on my iPad until I beat the chick at the top of the mountain who answers your question. Maybe it's a game center glitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not supposed to have that many hit points: in the first rebirth, no enemy exceeds 600 hit points (with most clocking in around 400-500).

In the first *Infinity Blade*, you could unlock the negative bloodline by doing things in a specific way. You may have inadvertently unlocked an ultra-ultra hardcore based on your actions during the first area. You may want to try creating a new character and noting what you do. If you remember what specific you did the first time (like say, lost to a specific foe), try doing things differently.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, the first enemy after the tutorial is not supposed to have that many hitpoints.

It was an easily beatable enemy, although I can't remember who or what *exactly* it was.

Comment: This is my experience as well. I don't remember how powerful he was, but I didn't have any problem defeating him.